# Indigo is unable to launch RQT_plot

Tags: ros-indigo, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have attempted to launch rqt_plot on my machine running Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo to no avail. I have also reinstalled rqt_plot and all its dependencies manually. When I attempt to run rqt_plot ROS spits back the following error

```
merciez@ln14ds7:~/catkin_ws$ rqt_plot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rqt_plot", line 6, in <module>
    from rqt_plot.plot import Plot
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot/plot.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .data_plot import DataPlot
ImportError: No module named data_plot
```

I have replicated the same error on three different machines all running Ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo.

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187270/indigo-is-unable-to-launch-rqt_plot/) by [JM](https://answers.ros.org/users/19800/jm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This should be fixed in the next release of rqt_plot; version 0.3.8

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just solved the problem with a hackish solution. Indigo apparently does not have data_plot installed for some strange reason. The solution I found was to take data_plot from Hydro and manually install into Indigo.

1. Find Indigo's rqt_plot (/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_plot)
2. Create a new folder called data_plot
3. Download and unzip the rqt_common_plugins file from Hydro (h ttps://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins)
4. Locate the Hydro data_plot folder from the rqt_common_plugins download (/rqt_common_plugins-groovy-devel/rqt_plot/src/rqt_plot) there should be 4 files inside __ init__.py, mat_data_plot.py, pytqtgraph_data_plot.py, and qwt_data_plot.py.
5. Move the 4 Hydro data_plot files to the Indigo data_plot folder you created earlier
6. Run rqt_plot

Note: you will have to use sudo to move the files to Indigo.

---

Originally posted by [JM](https://answers.ros.org/users/19800/jm/) with karma: 11 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1